# How to send multi @Field from List in android retrofit 1.9?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, retrofit

I don't want to fix @Field name to send order. I need to send to server like that `Key is 440005` and `Value is 3,Juice,` That data exist in sqlite database. 440005 is demo, actually call from `String code = cart.getSubMenuItemCode()` 3 is `cart.getQty()` and Juice is `cart.getName()` Now, I test index 0 for 1 row to send but actually want to send multi row.

API,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Order/Order")
void postOrder(@Field("table_no") String table,
               @Field("waiter_no") String waiter,
               @Field("440005") String code, // demo 440005
               Callback<Message> callback);
```

AddtoCartActivity,

```
btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<Cart> carts = db.getAllCarts();
            /*for (Cart cart : carts) {
                Log.d("item_code", cart.getSubMenuItemCode());
                Log.d("qty", cart.getQty());
                Log.d("description", cart.getName());
            }*/
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append(carts.get(0).getQty()).append(",");
            result.append(carts.get(0).getName()).append(",");
            NetworkEngine.getInstance().postOrder(tableNo, waiterNo, result.toString(), new Callback<Message>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Message message, Response response) {
                    Toasty.success(CartActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });


        }
    });
```

**[Postman]**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: Using **@FieldMap** annotation

**Step 1**: Change method in your service interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Order/Order")
void postOrder(@Field("table_no") String table_no, @Field("waiter_no") String waiter_no, @FieldMap Map<String, String> order,
               Callback<Message> callback);
```

**Step 2**: Create your ordermap

```
Map<String, String> order = new HashMap<>();
order.put("440055", "5, Noodle");
order.put("440057", "2, Salad Soup");
order.put("440059", "1, Champagne");
// Put more data here if you want
...
```

**Step 3**: Pass the map to your retrofit method

```
NetworkEngine.getInstance().postOrder("table_1", "waiter_47", order, new Callback<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Message message, Response response) {
                Toasty.success(CartActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello, I use Retrofit 1.9. `(params, callback);` callback is shown red text and then `@FieldMap<String, String> params,`

Comment: callback here I just give an example for you. Please replace your callback instance instead. btw could you please add your gradle file?

Comment: what in gradle file?

Comment: Retrofit dependencies line

Comment: it doesn't work, It send 3 rows with table_no,waiter_no, etc `"5, Noodle"` come from List. `table_no, waiter_no` is only one time. Can I use like this `(     @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/Order/Order")
    void postOrderr(
            @Field("table_no") String table_no,
            @Field("waiter_no") String waiter_no,
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> params,
            Callback<Message> callback); )`

Comment: I want to use one line and combine `order.put` like this `(table="6"&waiter="1"&440055="5,Noodle"&440057="2,Salad"&440057="1,Champagne")` please sir